# call a function with (req, res) inside other function in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have functions addVideosFromAuthor and schedule. I want schedule function will call addVideosFromAuthor and set the time to run. But when I call addVideosFromAuthor(), I got error `TypeError: undefined is not iterable!`. Look like the data can't be read in schedule function.

Is this code correct? Can you help me with this issue?

```
// @input array: [url, url2...]
export const addVideosFromAuthor = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // processing...
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

// @input object with array url: {command:'start', url: [url, url2...]}
export const schedule = (req, res) => {
    const cmd = req.body.command

    const task = cron.schedule('0 0 0 * * *', () => {
        addVideosFromAuthor(req.body.url, res)
    })

    if (cmd === 'start') {
        task.start()
    } else if (cmd === 'stop') {
        task.stop()
    } else {
        task.destroy()
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you read the error? What line number is it pointing to?

Comment: I mean the way I use it `addVideosFromAuthor(req.body.url, res)`

Comment: You pasted two separate lines. What line number is the error pointing to?

Comment: I assume your function is expecting a request object - then pass it the request object. Don't pass it the url unless it is expecting a url

Comment: I updated the code above with @input. The addVideosFromAuthor will received an array. The schedule will be an object with url array inside.